# Android Picasso callback when using target

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have a method that creates targets for Picasso like this:

```
private void createTargets() {
    Target target;

    for (Id id : itemids) {
        target = picassoImageTarget(getContext(), "imageDir", id.getId() + ".png");
        imgTargets.add(new ImgTarget(id.getId(), target));
    }
}
```

and then I download images to disk this way:

```
private void download() {
    for (ImgTarget imgTarget : imgTargets) {

        Picasso.with(getContext()).load("https://www.sestavsisvujsvet.cz/files/magnetky/" + imgTarget.getId() + ".png").into(imgTarget.getTarget());

    }
}
```

it does what I want it to do, however I am unable to get a callback, because the constructor with callback exists only when using ImageView:

[image: Ctrl + P]

Can someone help me find a solution to this? I don't understand callbacks and things like that too much, so it's hard for me to figure it out.

I just need to know when the whole downloading process has finished so I can notify the user.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A picasso `Target` is essentially a callback, if you look at the `Target` object, it has the following structure:

```
Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        // Notify the user
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
        // Notify the user
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
};
```

In your function `picassoImageTarget(...)` you would be building that target, and inside the `onBitmapLoaded` and `onBitmapFailed` you can put your code in to notify the user depending on your implementation.
Also, I noticed you are using `Picasso.with(context)`, this has been updated to `Picasso.get()` in the latest library, might be worthwhile updating your picasso library to the latest too.